# use php to fetch table data and arrange

Tags: php, arrays

I guess I don't give title nicely, anyways, I can explain it better here:

for example, the code is :

```
    <table>
            <tr>
                <td align="center"><span id="sn2">1</span></td>
                <td align="center"><div class="name">prakash</div></td>
                <td align="center"><span id="id2">student </span></td>
                <td><span id="surname1">timilsina</span></td>
                <td align="center"><span id="country1">nepal</span></td>
                <td align="center">date and time</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center"><span id="sn2">2</span></td>
                <td align="center"><div class="name">aakash</div></td>
                <td align="center"><span id="id2">student</span></td>
                <td><span id="surname2">singh</span></td>
                <td align="center"><span id="country2">india</span></td>
                <td align="center">date and time</td>
            </tr>
    </table>
```

What we need to do using php is, get the value in array like this :

```
    prakash -> timilsina
    aakash  -> singh
```

only the name and surname from the table given. I have no idea how do I do this. hoping to get it solved here.

Thanks in advance
cheers

Comment: Where does this data come from? It's probably much easier to use the original datasource rather then hacking around tables like this.

Comment: You want the value in one array after submit the page?

Comment: So, you want the first name to be the key and the last name to be the value in an associative array? Doesn't seem like a good idea...what if two people have the same first name? Also, are you stuck with this HTML design or are you able to modify it? How is the data being transferred to the PHP (form submission? `file_get_contents`?)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using preg_match_all this becomes quite easy. Just the regular expression that might be complex if you're not used to it. Look up a very complete tutorial at: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

```
<?php
$data = '
<table>
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><span id="sn2">1</span></td>
        <td align="center"><div class="name">prakash</div></td>
        <td align="center"><span id="id2">student </span></td>
        <td><span id="surname1">timilsina</span></td>
        <td align="center"><span id="country1">nepal</span></td>
        <td align="center">date and time</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><span id="sn2">2</span></td>
        <td align="center"><div class="name">aakash</div></td>
        <td align="center"><span id="id2">student</span></td>
        <td><span id="surname2">singh</span></td>
        <td align="center"><span id="country2">india</span></td>
        <td align="center">date and time</td>
    </tr>
</table>';

$results = preg_match_all('#<div class="name">(.*?)</div>#i', $data, $matchesSurNames);
$results = preg_match_all('#<span id="surname[0-9]+">(.*?)</span>#i', $data, $matchesNames);

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($matchesSurNames[1]);
var_dump($matchesNames[1]);
echo '</pre>';
```

Will result in

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "prakash"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "aakash"
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "timilsina"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "singh"
}
```